# Is the Claims To Windows Token Service still required to be running in WIF 4.5?

Tags: wif, impersonation, claims-based-identity

As the title really - Windows Identity Foundation is now baked into the .NET Framework 4.5. All the samples online are using the older Microsoft.Identity namespaces and require the C2WTS service to be running in order to do a WindowsIdentity upn logon (as well as adding the service account to the c2wtshost.exe.config file).

In .NET 4.5 we can now use the WindowsIdentity constructor and pass in a upn to do impersonation. I notice that the service is still installed, and I'm not sure if it needs to be running or not.